# segmentation fault when two unrelated c code put together

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The main function has 2 codes. I am learning arrays and pointers. I am more interested in why the code threw segmentation fault when the two parts are put together. And they run fine when they are run individually

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct nodeT{
    int data;
    struct nodeT *left;
    struct nodeT *right;
}node;

insert(node **root, int data){
    if(*root == NULL){
        node *elem;
        elem = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        elem->data = data;
        elem->left = NULL;
        elem->right = NULL;
        *root = elem;
    }
    else{
        if((*root)->data > data){
            insert(&((*root)->left),data);
        }
        else{
            insert(&((*root)->right),data);
        }
    }

}
inorder(node *root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
update(int A[]){
    A[3] = 1000;    
}

main(){

//PART 1

    node *root;
    insert(&root,5);
    insert(&root,6);
    insert(&root,8);
    insert(&root,1);
    insert(&root,9);
    inorder(root);

// PART 2
    int A[10];
    int  i  = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        A[i] = i;
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        printf("%d \n", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    update(A);
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        printf("%d \n", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because root is uninitialised, it should be null (probably). So you're getting undefined behaviour.

Also main should return a value (only because c allows you to omit 'int' does that compile). Your code will tell the client it exited with an unpredictable error.

Comment: Thanks. node *root  = NULL worked. But any explanation why it is working when the PART 2 was commented

Comment: not enough reputation to upvote :). I am new to the community. I will try to learn the etiquettes.

Comment: ah. never mind, i'm sure it'll happen. thanks for the accept (and you also get reputation for accepting an answer, which is another reason for accepting)

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem here I think

```
insert(node **root, int data){

    if(*root == NULL){
```

inside your `insert` function. This combined with the following

```
node *root;
insert(&root,5);
```

is a problem because you are not explicitly setting `root` to NULL inside `main()` and so its address could in theory be any arbitrary value.

Whenever `root` is not NULL you are accessing values that you have no business accessing such as here

```
(*root)->data > data
```

This will likely segfault with `root` not explicitly set to NULL at the start of `main()`.

As for saying that each part of the code runs "fine" when run separately then I would say that must have just been good luck because part 1 of your code has a clear problem.